# How to customize GCM Message Builder

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-messaging

i have everything setup and able to send receive with gcm. but how to customized the notification received?

Code:

```
Message message = new Message.Builder()
.addData("message", "testing")
.build();
```

Notification received in emulator:-

```
GCM Notification 
 Received: Bundle[{message=testing}]
```

I would like to change the title **GCM Notification** and remove those received stuff. Been searching the web and unable to find. Thanks for your help.

Comment: you mean you want to change gcm log tag / message ?

Comment: yup.. at the moment the header is titled GCM Notification and no thumbnail pic.

Comment: who cares about a log message ? You may just to remove it in the released version of your app. But why changing log messages ?

Comment: it's not log i mean.. when u get notifcation on your mobile, you will get "testing" msg along with the header "GCM Notification". I would like to edit that header, as well as removed "Received: Bundle[{message=" leaving just testing as the content in notification

Comment: It's unclear. When you talk about notification do you talk about the push message that is received from GCM or the notification in the usual Android meaning : something displayed in the notification bar.

Comment: something displayed in notification bar (the bar on top of your mobile phone).. (but I thought it's the push message from GCM that make something display in notification bar? )

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this document from Google, it will explain you how to convert a GCM message to a notification : http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html
(section "Receive a message").

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for the tips. Silly me, I thought whatever msg sent from gcm server(from the message builder) will be posted as it is in the app.

Didn't know i need to process the msg received from the client itself

```
private void sendNotification(String msg) {
        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                new Intent(this, DemoActivity.class), 0);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_gcm)
        .setContentTitle("GCM Notification") //this is the place I am looking for
        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
        .bigText(msg))
        .setContentText(msg);

        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
    }
```